# Regular expressión that matches

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this text:

> Habitación 101

As you can see there is a letter with an accent: ó

Im looking for a regular expressión that matches also when the word is written **without accent**, that is "habitacion".

I'm using JavaScript's `new RegExp(keyword, 'u')`.

Comment: `/habitacion|Habitación/`

Comment: /\w+/u' try this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well simply use [`Habitaci[ó|o]n`](https://regex101.com/r/pSA5nk/1) as regex.

```
const regex = new RegExp('Habitaci[ó|o]n', 'gi');
```

Where `[ó|o]` matches a single character in the list `ó|o`.

This is a Demo:

```js
const regex = new RegExp('Habitaci[ó|o]n', 'gi');
const str = `Habitación
Habitacion`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
}
```